# is it necessary or useful Meteor.startup(function () {}) when publishing a collection?

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

basically I have:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
   "use strict";

   Meteor.publish("uTree", function () {
        return utree.find({});
   });
});
```

so the question is should I wait or not for the system is up and running to start publishing? is any advantage of using Meteor.startup() in here?

Answer (score 4):

**short answer**

The `startup` callback is unnecessary in this case.

**long answer**

The only reason you'd wrap a publisher in a `startup` callback is out of concern that some part of the server code (a package, collection, etc.) had not yet been evaluated.

In order for a publish function to be activated, there needs to exist a connected client making the request. In order for a connected client to exist, the server must already be running. If the server is already running, it has already evaluated all of its scripts.

Therefore, the `startup` callback is unnecessary in this case. Q.E.D.